# Is there a way to get a node that the cursor is in?

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a way to get the node that the cursor or mouse is in?

In the following image the cursor is inside the head tag (meta.tag.tag-name.xml)

[image]

The method that I'm looking for would return all the text from "<head>" to toe, I mean, "</head>". Or maybe it would return the node object inside a hierarchy of objects.

In the same example if you put the cursor inside the CSS "html, body" brackets the method would return:

```
html, body  {
    height:100%;
}
```

or

```
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in method to do this. But jumtoMatching function does something similar https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.0/lib/ace/editor.js#L2021.
I think you can modify it to return the range instead of selecting it.

Comment: I'll look into it. Did you see my patch in the other question? Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, it is helpful, however it seems to give unnecessarily fine grained control over a feature very few will want to change, why would anyone want to disable that?

Comment: Well, you might as well ask why does anyone want to do anything? You might as well ask why is a tree good? Why is the sunset good? People just want to do what they want to do for who knows why.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean to ask it in such a vague way. I meant there are myriads of features to implement, and adding features that almost no one will use takes space from features many people want to use. As i understand you don't want to use this settings, just want to add them to the option panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ace.on("create", function(e) {
        var editor = e.editor;
        var ace = editor.ace;
        ace.on("mousemove", function(ev) {

            //LIMITS the numbers of characters per function search to 30 
            var line = ev.editor.getSelectedText();
            if (letter != line && line != ""&& line.length < 50){
            console.log(line);
            letter = line;
                }
            });
        }, plugin);
```